MobaXTerm script syntax error when trying to connect to database
I am having an issue, I am getting this following error after executing the code below
wrong # args: should be "set varName ?newValue?"
    while executing
"set cmd sqlcmd -S '$server -d $database -U $username -P $password -Q '$sql_query''"
    (procedure "get_commands_from_db" line 10)
    invoked from within
"get_commands_from_db $server $database $username $password $sql_query"
    invoked from within
"set commands [get_commands_from_db $server $database $username $password $sql_query]"
    (file "./SampleTest3" line 46)

#!/usr/bin/expect

# Define database connection parameters
set server "App"
set database "comp"
set username "USERNAME"
set password "PASSWORD"

# Define the SQL query to fetch commands
set sql_query "SELECT Code FROM tblValues;"

# Define the list of servers
set servers {
    111.21.221.111
}

# Function to get commands from the database
proc get_commands_from_db {server database username password sql_query} {
    set commands_list [list]
    
    puts "DEBUG: Server: $server"
puts "DEBUG: Database: $database"
puts "DEBUG: Username: $username"
puts "DEBUG: SQL Query: $sql_query"
    
    # Prepare SQLCMD command
    set cmd sqlcmd -S '$server -d $database -U $username -P $password -Q '$sql_query''
    
    # Run SQLCMD and capture output
    set output [exec $cmd]
    
    # Split output into lines
    set lines [split $output "\n"]
    
    # Process lines and append to commands list
    foreach line $lines {
        if {[string length $line] > 0} {
            lappend commands_list $line
        }
    }
    
    return $commands_list
}

# Fetch commands from the database
set commands [get_commands_from_db $server $database $username $password $sql_query]

# Execute commands on remote servers
foreach server $servers {
    spawn ssh $username@$server
    expect {
        "password:" {
            send "$password\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        "==> " {
            send "1\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        "pcarr@idxhost ~> " {
            # Execute each command from the database
            foreach cmd $commands {
                send "$cmd\r"
                expect "$ "
            }
            send "exit\r"
        }
        "logout" {
            send "exit\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        "Connection closed" {
            send "exit\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        timeout {
            puts "Connection to $server timed out"
            continue
        }
    }
}

I think there is a problem with my syntax around the query. I tried multiple compbinations of single quotes, double quotes, and escapes but nothing is working for me. I am wondering if thee are any other ideas?

Sorry I am not sure how to format the error correctly so it looks good. :(

There's a syntax problem on the set cmd line and the exec just afterwards probably needs changes too. (I formatted your error for you. Tricks of knowing the site...)
